# php/SQL returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I'll be the first to admit I'm an idiot, but is there any reason for why this query returns NULL? The connection to the DB is working just fine and I'm able to POST to it.

```
<?php
$servername = "server";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db-name";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytablename";
$results = mysqli_query($sql,$conn);

if ($results !== false) {
    var_dump($results);
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: What is the `tablename`? `TABLE`?

Comment: you are not getting any result or not able to connect to db ? what is returing `null`

Comment: Table is a keyword. To escape it use backticks or rename your table. SELECT * FROM `TABLE`

Comment: `mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )`

Comment: Well you need to put more information in this post. Where do you get the null? Did you really want to query a table named table?

Comment: Sorry, I altered the tables real name - understand that it was confusing. Changed to something more descriptive.

Comment: Because you using (`$results !== false`) and `!==` need to be `!=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqli_query` needs the first parameter to be the link identifier and the second be the query. Try with -

```
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

[DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

**Update**

`$results` be the resource, not the table data. If you need the data then you need to use

`$fetchData = mysqli_fetch_object($result)`

Comment: Thank you - at least something new happened now:

It returns the following:

object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(4) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM SMFB";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($results !== false) {
    mysqli_fetch_object($result)`

Like this? It returns nothing now.